# Intellij profiler feature is not found in 2021 community version

Tags: intellij-idea, profiler

Follow the instruction at:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cpu-profiler.html#in-this-section

But profiler (menu,settings, etc) not found in Intellij 2021.2 community version.
How to use a profiler with Intellij?

Comment: Why not use it with NetBeans? IntelliJ has to offer paying users something extra.

Answer (score 6):

This option is supported in Ultimate Edition only.